# Loading page on nextjs 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, state, loading

Hi im trying to get a loading page to show while website is taking the time to load. as it quite a large website I thought a loading screen would provide the best possible user experience however I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to work on nextjs 13. I have created a simple functional component that says loading... and have imported it directly into my layout.jsx folder.

I am using the app directory method which is quite new and im also new at nextjs so im a little lost  ^^

I imagine I might need to set state at some point but I cant seem to figure out when and where to do it

any advice would be great.

thanks

```
import "./globals.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Loading from "../components/loading/loading";

const Layout = ({ children, dataLoaded }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataLoaded) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [dataLoaded]);

  return (
    <body className="app {oswald.className}">
      {loading && <Loading />}
      {children}
    </body>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

.
.
.

**Attempt 1 -**

After following one of the answers below it does not seem like my loading page is showing up at all. and no errors showing up.

my layout is as follows

**layout.jsx**

```
import "./globals.css";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import Loading from "../components/loading/loading";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>{children}</Suspense>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**LoadingPage.js**

```
const LoadingPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="loading w-screen h-screen bg-red-100">
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoadingPage;
```

**Loading.js**

```
import LoadingPage from "@/components/loading/loading";

export default function Loading() {
  return <LoadingPage />;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In NextJS 13, there's actually a default way to handle loading states within pages. You can declare a `loading.tsx` file in your `/app` directory, with this content:

```
export default function Loading() {
  return <Loading />
}
```

Then, inside your `Layout`, you can wrap your page with a `Suspense` tag, like this:

```
<Layout>
  <Navbar>
  ...
  <Suspense fallback={<Loading/>}>
    <Page/>
  </Suspense>
</Layout>
```

Your `loading` state will be automatically handled upon navigation.

Comment: You don't need to wrap the `Page` component in a suspense boundary for this to work. I think you copied the second code snippet from the nextjs docs and it shows what the resulting component hierarchy would look like if you add the `loading.tsx` file. Nextjs adds the suspense boundary behind the scenes, you don't have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would want to enhance @saguirrews answer with more details.

Creating `loading.js`/`loading.tsx` in any specific folder `app`, `dashboard` and the like, would help you create Loading UI with [`React Suspense`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense)

[image]

[image]

##### Example

`app/dashboard/loading.tsx`

```
export default function Loading() {
  // You can add any UI inside Loading, including a Skeleton.
  return <LoadingSkeleton />
}
```

`app/dashboard/page.tsx`

```
<Layout>
  <Navbar>
  ...
  <Suspense fallback={<Loading/>}>
    <Page/>
  </Suspense>
</Layout>
```

For more details follow the official docs [Nextjs Loading](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming)