# `loading.tsx` does not work when building page for ISR

Tags: javascript, next.js, app-router

In Next JS 14 app router, when clicking on a `Link` component it does not change the URL immediately, and after some time the page loads. But the content from `loading.tsx` file does not appear while the page transition takes place. In regular pages (not ISR page), the loader shows up but it still takes time after clicking the link. `history.pushState` can be used to change the URL immediately, but the loader still shows up late.

I tried using `usePathname` hook to listen to a path change, but it takes time for the change.
I also tried adding `history.pushState` to `Link` component's onClick, with this the loading still takes a long time to load.

Comment: Are you using Suspense?

Comment: Also try adding a prefetch prop to the `<Link />` component

Comment: @Satindar31 Yes, I'm using the prefetch property as `true`. But when a page takes a long time to build, the loading does not show. This makes the user think nothing is going on.

Comment: Are you observing this in dev or after a build + deploy ? In dev, there is a compile time during which there is no feedback.

Comment: I'm observing after the build and deployment. It also does not work locally after building and running. In dev, the loading does show up. But after building, when a page is not previously built, it takes time to navigate. This is expected, but in this case, the loading does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the content doesn't show up is most probably because you have not used Suspense. Make sure to wrap your code in suspense like so.

```js
<Suspense fallback={<Loading />}
    <p>Hello world</p>
</Suspense>
```

If this does not work, try adding a prefetch prop to the link tag.

Comment: Next JS automatically wraps the contents of a page in `Suspense`. So, adding `Suspense` on layout will not make any difference.

Comment: @Debashish,
Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76609619/17408627

Comment: I already have this, but it does not work with ISR. It works when running in dev mode or when not using ISR.